# Why are additional parameters not present when using database connection for login on Auth0's Lock

Tags: ios, auth0, auth0-lock

I have been using Auth0's Lock widget for my app's Login flow. It works great, but now I need to pass additional parameters during login.

The Lock widget offers a `parameters` attribute which the docs say will be "sent with every authentication requests". Sounds great, so I put this together:

```
  let params = ["favoriteFood": Base64Encode("pizza")]
  Lock.classic().withOptions {
    $0.oidcConformant = true
    $0.allow = [.Login, .ResetPassword]
    ...
    $0.parameters = params
  }
```

The issue is, my custom parameters aren't showing up inside the login request when I login with a *database connection*. When I login with a *social connection* like google, I *am* seeing these parameters.

Has anyone else found a solution to this? Or can someone clarify the purpose of this "parameters" attribute, so I can better understand how to use it?

NOTE:
[The docs](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/sending-authentication-parameters) specify that "the following parameters are supported: `access_token, scope, protocol, device, request_id, nonce and state`", so I tried renaming my custom parameter "state" instead of "customParams", but the issue remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the Lock project. Auth0 team has fixed the issue and closed my ticket: https://github.com/auth0/Lock.swift/issues/506

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `params` is an array (`[]`).  The docs you reference seem to show it should be a json object (`{}`).

> auth: {
>       params: {state: 'foo'},   }

Comment: Thanks, but it's actually a dictionary initialized with one key "favoriteFood" and it's associated value Base64Encoded("pizza"), but the initialization of an array looks similar. This is written in Swift FYI